# Python read data from a file into a class

Tags: python, class

I have a filename 'my_data_file.csv' that is a comma separated file of 3 rows and 3 columns with random numbers. I want to read the data and store it into a class 'MYDATA'. Then I want to print the 3x3 array in the window by typing: class.function('my_file.csv'). This is my attempt:

```
class MYDATA:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        
        # get the main axis of the file.
        self.values = self.get_values_from_file()
      
    def get_values_from_file(self):
        values = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                pos = list(map(float, line.split(',')))
                values.append(pos)
        return values

print(MYDATA.get_values_from_file('my_data_file.csv'))
```

This gives me `NameError: name 'filename' is not defined`. What do I do wrong? How can I print the values to the screen? I do not want to define a classmethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer filename with self object. Also classname can only access class members, so self.filename wouldn't have worked.

```
class MYDATA:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        
        # get the main axis of the file.
        self.values = self.get_values_from_file()
      
    def get_values_from_file(self):
        values = []
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                pos = list(map(float, line.split(',')))
                values.append(pos)
        return values

mydataobj = MYDATA(r'my_data_file.csv')
print(mydataobj .get_values_from_file())
```

Comment: what do you mean with self.filename wouldnt have worked? It is in the answer right? You mean without self.filename it wouldnt have worked?

Comment: I mean if you would have tried accessing the meber using classname.variable then self.membername would have given you error inside the function

Comment: check this out https://pynative.com/python-class-method/